# when I load .off file in CGAL Polyhedron demo, nothing were showed in the window

Tags: cgal, polyhedra

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3mxO.png)
I have build the demo succesfully, and runs the demo, but when I try to load .off file, it comes out nothing. In the console window, the error message  " QWindowsNativeFieDialogBase::shellitem:SHCreateItemFromParsingName(file:debug)failed(no such file or direcory)"
Could somebody give me any instruction?

Comment: which demo are you talking about? what version of CGAL?  what compiler? what platform?

Comment: The demo named Polyhedron, located in "E:\CGAL-4.7\demo\Polyhedron".  Platform: Window 10 64bit, Visual studio 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams the problem is similar to this one : [http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-loading-off-files-in-Polyhedron-demo-td4661212.html][1]
 Do you build any plugin ? You need at least off_plugin to load an off file in addition of Polyhedron_3

Comment: thanks   it's exactly the same problem, I have solved it:)